# need to know what package created/resumed my activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an application that is secured with a password. Therefor i want the password dialog to show on all calls to onResume of any of my activities. The thing is that i do not want the password dialog to show when navigating inside my own application.

So, i want to know if the application was entered from within or outside the application. What is the best way to accomplish this?

The only idea i have now is to use the getCallingActivity method and check if it contains my package name. The problem with this is that it forces me to use startActivityForResult() instead of just startActivity() wich is painful because i need to search all my code and change that.

Comment: you probably could have changed all your calls to startACtivityForResult() in the time it took you to post this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Android permission system, your protected activity can require a permission in order to be started. That permission would be defined in your manifest and it would be defined as requiring the same package signature to be granted.

The activity end users start would be the one that performs password verification; once it's satisfied it would start your protected activity. Attempts to start your protected activities by packages other than your own would fail.

Answer (score 0):

From your inside code you could provide an extra field to the Intent that is used to start the Activity. Within the started Activity, check if this extra field exists and if so, you know the Activity was started by inside code.

Comment: if someone outside the app figures out this scheme, they could circumvent the password dialog by adding the field themselves.

Comment: exactly (though unlikly), but i would like to not rewrite all my calls to startActivity() ^^ but i will i have to ofcourse